# Extract parts from bracketed string

Tags: regex, string, brackets

There is a string some parts of which are marked w/brackets:

```
abc(de)f(uv)xyz
```

How to split it into parts like:

```
abc | false
de | true
f | false
uv | true
xyz | false
```

Where *true* stands for a bracketed part and *false* stands for an unbracketed one.

*N.B.* Brackets are only used for marking purpose. Nested, unpaired brackets and other complex scenarious are not possible.

Comment: What’s the expected output - just the parts or the `true`/`false` as well?

Comment: Also, is the syntax of the string guaranteed to be consistent and correct, meaning will opening and closing brackets always match like `abc(de)f` or can there also be random brackets like `abcd)e(f)`?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa Both parts and booleans. The output should allow it to iterate over and recover the source string.

Comment: @AndreasPizsa Bracket sequence is guaranteed to be valid and not to contain nested sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Regular Expression

Given that the bracket sequence is guaranteed to be valid and not to contain nested sequences, we can keep the regular expression quite simple:

`\(?([^()]+)\)?`

1. `\(?` - optionally accept an opening bracket
2. `([^()]+)`- capture anything that’s not an opening or closing bracket
3. `\)?` - optionally accept a closing bracket

## The Code

#### Executing the Regular Expression

Once we execute the regex (`execAll(pattern, text)`) we get

```js
const matches = execAll(pattern, text)

[
  ['abc', 'abc'],
  ['(de)', 'de'],
  ['f'   , 'f' ]
  ['(uv)', 'uv'],
  ['xyz', 'xyz']
]
```

#### Bracketed vs unbracketed

Index `0` of each entry is the matched text and index `1` is the captured group.

Looking at the first character of index `0` tells us whether it’s a group or not:

```js
matches[0][0] === '(' // false
matches[1][0] === '(' // true
```

#### Bringing it in the right order

We want the text first and the boolean second:

```js
matches.map(([bracket, group]) => [group, bracket[0]==='('])

[
  ['abc', false],
  ['de' , true ],
  ['f'  , false]
  ['uv' , true ],
  ['xyz', false]
]
```

Done!

## Solution

```js
const execAll = (pattern, str) => {
    const result=[]
    let match
    while((match = pattern.exec(str))) {
        result.push(match)
    }
    return result
}

const extractGroups = text => {
  const pattern = /\(?([^()]+)\)?/g
  const matches = execAll(pattern, text)
  return matches
    .map(([bracket, group]) => [group, bracket[0]==='('])
}
  
console.log(extractGroups('abc(de)f(uv)xyz'))
```